# C# Way to enforce all classes have a method of a given name

Tags: c#

I am not sure if this even makes sense hence asking it widely.
Is it possible for enforce that a set of classes always implements a function with a given **name**. The method in each class might have different signature - but should have the same name. Some like below:

```
public class ClassOne {
    public int GetSomething (int a, int b, out int c) { }
}

public class ClassTwo {
    public int GetSomething ( int a, out string b) {}
}
```

I want anyone who writes `ClassThree` or `ClassFour` as part of this library to implement the `GetSomething` method. Is there a C# construct that allows one to enforce this?

Not looking at design review of this - just want to know if its possible at all without manually enforcing via code reviews.

Comment: Use an interface!

Comment: why not implementing so many  interfaces this is interface segregation principle

Comment: Why you need this at all? Why do you want a common name for a method which may do *anything* and probably also *return anything*? If you want to force all classes have a given member make that member abstract in the base-class. However this makes only sense when the signature and thus the API is allways the same.,

Comment: What is the purpose of a class with method of unknown arguments. It is just illogical in terms of OOP. How are you going to call this method? If arguments are homogeneous then you could just use single `Dictionary<string, object>` parameter or `params object[] args`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Given the OP mentioned code-reviews - I suspect the OP wants to enforce a consistent naming convention in their project(s), e.g. ensuring their programmers use "Get" instead of "Retrieve" or "Fetch", for example.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that with out-of-the-box C#. C# has abstract classes and interfaces, but they require a specific signature for a method, not just a name.

You could get this working by creating [code analyzers in Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers), where you check your code if it has the required method.

However, I don't think you should all this. I think you are making a design flaw here in requiring a method with a specific name, without forcing the arguments of it.

You could always implement a method similar to the `Main` method found in every C# application. It uses a `string[]` as parameter where you can put a number of variables in. In your case I would opt for an `object[]`. However, this design has its flaws too obviously.

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of a class with method of unknown arguments. It is just illogical in terms of OOP. How are you going to call this method? If arguments are homogeneous then you could just do something like:

```
public interface IBaseInterface
{
    public int GetSomething(Dictionary<string, object> args); // keys matter
}
```

or

```
public interface IBaseInterface
{
    public int GetSomething(params object[] args); // order matters
}
```

In some cases `Func<>` / `Action<>` high-order functions may be useful.
If you provide a usage case, we would be able to make a more precise answer. 
Show how you are going to call such method and I will try to show how to make it better.

Answering your question only from **technical** side, you could do the following:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected BaseClass() 
    {
        if (this.GetType().GetMethod("GetSomething") == null) 
            throw new InvalidOperationException("BaseClass subclasses should implement 'GetSomething' method");
    }
}

public class ClassOne : BaseClass {
    public int GetSomething (int a, int b, out int c) { }
}

public class ClassTwo : BaseClass {
    public int GetSomething (int a, out string b) {}
}
```

It **will not** guarantee this behavior at design-time, but will ensure that such methods exists at **run-time**.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an interface with the method you want.
2. Set classes inherit from this interace

   interface ISampleInterface
       {
           void SampleMethod();
       }

   ```
   class ImplementationClass1 : ISampleInterface
   {
       // Explicit interface member implementation: 
       void ISampleInterface.SampleMethod()
       {
           // Method implementation.
       }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

How about encapsulating parameters in a "Criteria" object?

```
public interface IGettable
{
    int GetSomething (Criteria crit);
}

public class Criteria
{
    public CriteriaType type {get; set;};
    public int a {get; set;};
    public int b {get; set;};
    ...

    public static Criteria ClassOneCriteria(int a, int b)
    {
        return new Criteria
        {
            type = CriteriaType.ClassOneCriteria, 
            a = a,
            b = b
        }
    }
    ...
}

public enum CriteriaType
{
    ClassOneCriteria,
    ClassTwoCriteria
}

public class ClassOne : IGettable
{
    public int GetSomething (Criteria crit) 
    { 
        if (crit.type != CriteriaType.ClassOneCriteria)
            throw new Exception("Invalid criteria type for Class One");
        ...
    }
}
```